# Falling to install Remi repo: RHEL 7.4

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, r, rhel-7, subscription

How to force subscription manager to accept REMI repo?
I'm not sure how to proceed. I've already spent 3 hours looking for a solution.

What I want in the end is to be able to install R (`yum install -y R`), but there're dependencies which require other repos, namely REMI so that I can install **pcre2-devel**

Really appreciate a solution. Thanks!

```
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

# yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
remi-release-7.rpm                                                                            |  17 kB  00:00:00
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-efHRDy/remi-release-7.rpm: remi-release-7.7-1.el7.remi.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-efHRDy/remi-release-7.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation is in the error message, **remi-release** is already installed.

But notice that RHEL 7.4 is outdated and unmaintained. Current version is 7.7.

Comment: Does it mean, I have to use at least RHEL 7.7? If yes, I don't have the luxury to choose, RHEL is based on company current policy. Is there any workaround?

Comment: This means that it may work... or not... and won't be supported (some dependencies have change, and so, may be missing).
BTW even RH doesn't support 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error on Centos 7. and this is what I fixed.

Reinstall the epel-release  if you installed it

**Check**

```
yum install epel-release
```

Package matching epel-release-7-11.noarch already installed. Checking for update.

**Next remove epel-release**

```
yum remove epel-release -y
yum update
```

**Next epel-release 7.13**

```
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```